# How do I find the places mentioned in my bounties?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Over the last few days, I've gotten a number of bounties and don't know where to go.  For example, I have worth 15k credits in a place called United Gold Systems Andrew, and I have no clue where that is.

**Is there a way to look up or locate the places named in my bounties?**

Comment: I cleaned up your question to make it easier to read, and changed the tag since I was 99% sure you were talking about Elite: Dangerous, not King's Bounty.  Feel free to edit it again or revert my edits if you disagree with them (to edit further, just click 'edit' right under the tag; to revert my edit, click where it says 'edited X time ago' over my name, next to yours.)

Comment: will sit down in 8 hrs time and work it out

Comment: @gatherer818 Good job cleaning that one up +1

Comment: Where do you see this? Is it under Transactions - Claims or under Missions?

Comment: Yeah, It could be a pain to cash all the bounties you have, especially if you use the warrent scanner, but if you don't, a good habit is to always cash your bounties before you travel to another system.

Answer (score 2):

It can get a bit complicated...

The "place" to turn in your bounty is *not* a place. The bounty shows the *faction* that you turn it in with.

For the purposes of turning in bounties, there are 3 types of faction:

1. A major faction (Alliance, Empire, Federation). You can turn these in at any station in a system with a presence from a faction connected to one of these. (though I often hold onto these to turn it at community goals)
2. A minor faction with their primary system name in the faction name. (Examples: "Eranin Industry", "Pirates of HIP 74255") These you can always turn in at the system whose name is in the faction, but may be able to turn in at stations in other systems.
3. A minor faction without the system name in the faction name. (Example: "Gold United Systems") These are harder to track down...

Note: it's very rare to have bounties (from NPCs) that require traveling very far. They tend to be from the nearest systems, or from the major factions.

For a faction with the system name in it, you can just search for the system name in the galaxy map.

In-game, you should be able to start with the list of nearby systems (look at navigation panel), then go into galaxy map, get to the system view for a system, and in the system info tab for a system, you can see a list of all the factions present in that system. (might have to click the button to buy data for the system to get into the system view)

Outside of the game, you can use google, https://eddb.io and other tools to find factions. Generally the info outside the game will only contain the faction that controls the system.

I don't know about "United Gold Systems", but it looks like "Gold United Systems" controls GD 215: https://eddb.io/system/5149